# How do I prevent Tiny Death Star from crashing when trying to collect an imperial items reward?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star, windows-phone

I'm playing Tiny Death Star on Windows Phone. The game crashes whenever I tap 'collect reward' on the imperial items screen, thus causing the reward not being collected.

In other words, it is impossible for me to collect the rather hefty reward of 70,700, or any reward after it. Do you guys know how to avoid this problem?

Comment: Might be a corrupted installation. Tried to delete and reinstall? (not sure how progress is saved so watch out for that)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, given the game's structure, there are practically no work-arounds for bugs. You can try a reinstall, but most people have had little luck getting their progress back after that.

About the only thing I can think of, try building one more any of the items and see if it works after that. It might force the program to rebuild a file in doing so.  But, I'm spitballing on that one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same thing on WP8 and on Windows 8.1. 
I think this happens when you attempt to collect the reward for the LAST Imperial task, and the game code is not handling correctly the case when there are no more new tasks to give out. I'm seeing the same behavior (game crash) when I attempt to skip the last task.

Comment: This is actually a slightly different problem than the poster has been experiencing.  Many people have been reporting a crash when attempting to pay 100 BUX in order to skip the "Build another imperial level" screen after you've built all 16.